# python spacy loop to parse out lemma and add special case on token

Tags: python, loops, spacy, lemmatization

Python is a new beast and I decided to go beyond just the basics and actually put a package to use. I'm testing that out with spacy - so bare with me on the basics. I think this is a case of you don't know what you don't know, and therefore, I appreciate any help.

I'm trying to loop through the following sentences to parse out the lemma, identify the verb and noun, and then change the noun to special case. I can get close, but I can't get the final result I want which is to look like:
['Fly', 'San Francisco']

Here is what I've got so far...

```
 import spacy
 from spacy.symbols import ORTH, LEMMA
 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

 doc=nlp(u'I have flown to LA. Now I am flying to Frisco.')

 special_case=[{ORTH: u'Frisco', LEMMA: u'San Francisco'}]
 nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'Frisco', special_case)


 for sent in doc.sents:
     print([w.lemma_ for w in sent if 
         w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VB' or 
         w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VBG'])
     print(
         [w.lemma_ for w in sent if 
         w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VB' or 
         w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VBG' or 
         w.dep_ =='pobj'])
```

Here is the output I get:

```
[]
['LA']
['fly']
['fly', 'Frisco']
```

Any input? What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't it that you should do `doc=nlp(u'I have flown to LA. Now I am flying to Frisco.')` AFTER having added the new token with `nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'Frisco', special_case)`? May not be this but that's what I'd say from seeing your code!

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince Okay! Good to know. That gets me closer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the custom tokenization to the nlp object, before using the nlp object to create the doc.

```
    import spacy
    from spacy.symbols import ORTH, LEMMA

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    special_case = [{ORTH: u'Frisco', LEMMA: u'San Francisco'}]
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'Frisco', special_case)

    doc = nlp(u'I have flown to LA. Now I am flying to Frisco.')

    for sent in doc.sents:
        print([w.lemma_ for w in sent if
               w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VB' or
               w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VBG'])
        print(
            [w.lemma_ for w in sent if
             w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VB' or
             w.dep_ == 'ROOT' and w.tag_ == 'VBG' or
             w.dep_ == 'pobj'])
```